# using bisect with tuples in python

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search, bisect

I am trying to understand the use of bisect function in the python's bisect module and how to use it with tuples. I have seen that it takes a list and a value to find the index to place the value. In my case the value is a tuple. This is from leetcode 981 https://leetcode.com/problems/time-based-key-value-store/. A is a list of tuple and the tuple will contain (int,string) as its data.

```
class TimeMap(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.M = collections.defaultdict(list)

def set(self, key, value, timestamp):
    self.M[key].append((timestamp, value))

def get(self, key, timestamp):
    A = self.M.get(key, None)
    if A is None: return ""
    i = bisect.bisect(A, (timestamp, chr(127)))
    return A[i-1][1] if i else ""
```

I understand what they are trying to do for solving the question . I just want to understand why use chr(127). I tried using None but it gives an error. I am guessing that it will always take the first int value in the tuple because the chr(127) will always be unqualified somehow for bisect to accept. But I am not able to find the correct reason for this. also IDLE shows chr(127) as \x7f and found out its a non ascii character.

Answer (score 1):

Python compares tuples element by element and from left to right. For example:

`(1, 2) > (1, 1)` is `True`

`(1, 2) > (1, 2)` is `False`

I guess, they use `chr(127)`, to make the second item in the tuple larger than any other character.

`(1, chr(127)) > (1, 'z')` is `True`

Comment: you are right. bisect will compare the tuple from left to right and  the string value would always be greater than any string in the list of tuples A. as a result bisect will be able to compare correctly. found out in the leetcode discussion forum

Answer (score 0):

finally found some  understanable solution in leetcode discussion forum. all credits go to leetcode users
https://leetcode.com/slvher/ and https://leetcode.com/jcodem/

The ascii code range of lower char is [97, 122], thus chr(127) can be used to make sure the located index from bisect.bisect(A, (timestamp, chr(127))) can satisfy the condition: timestamp_prev <= timestamp. In fact, chr(ascii_v) can also be used here where ascii_v's range is [123, 127].